# USB port detect only SSD and not mouse or microphone

Tags: windows, usb, laptop, mouse, microphone

I have encountered a strange issue with my laptop recently. The side door of my laptop has started to behave strangely: the only thing it manages to connect is my external SSD; my mouse and microphone do not connect.

For context, the microphone and mouse used on other computers do not have any issues. I thought it might be because I'm using a USB Hub, but the problem persists even when directly attached to the USB port. Further tests connecting everything to the hub but on a different PC do not generate any problems.

For further context, the USB 3.0 ports belong to the laptop, SSD, and USB Hub. The microphone and mouse are 2.0. Additionally, the SSD works when connected through the Hub, whereas the mouse and microphone are not detected regardless.

So far, I have tried resetting and attempting to disconnect the USB port directly from the device manager, but aside from a forced restart, I have not achieved anything. I've also tried checking the drivers, and they all seem to be in order. Do you have any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Is it a USB3 port and is it a USB3 HDD?

Comment: It is a USB 3 port and the SSD is also a USB 3, the USB Hub is also USB 3, only the mouse and the microphone is not USB 3 but USB 2

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your port's USB2 data pins are not making contact (or otherwise broken, perhaps internally).

USB3 devices still work because they *do not use* the original D+/D- (middle) pins for data – only the [new](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:USB_3.0.png) five pins (SSRX and SSTX) are used for data transfer in "SuperSpeed" mode.

(Hubs are the only devices that use both; but even then, they only use the USB2 D+/D- pins when relaying packets for a USB2 device, whereas the SSRX/SSTX lines are used when relaying for a USB3 device.)

Comment: I will check asap with a different USB cable for the microphone, there is a way to fix this problem that don't rely on sending the laptop back to the customer service?

Comment: @Batteo 1) Can you look inside the socket to see if there is an obvious problem? A phone camera might help. 2) A local computer repair shop will be able to replace the USB socket. It might even be one you can replace yourself without soldering - what's the make and model of the laptop?